# If char *ptr[10]={"ram","try"} then what is the difference between ptr ,*ptr , *ptr[0] , ptr[0] if all given four types used in printf function

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Compiler version gcc  6.3.0

int main()
{
  char *ptr[10]={"ram","try"};
  printf("%s \n",ptr);   // prints neither string nor character (may be address)(why ?)
  printf("%s \n",*ptr);  // prints string (why ?)
  printf("%c \n",*ptr[0]);   // prints character i.e. r ( why ?)
  printf("%s \n",ptr[0]);   // prints string (understandable)
  return 0;
}
```

Why ptr doesn't print **ram** ? and why *ptr[0] doesn't print string ?

Comment: Prince, save time and enable all warnings to get good quick feedback on some of the issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> char *ptr[10]={"ram","try"};
> ```

`ptr` is an array of 10 pointers: `ptr[0]`, ... to ... `ptr[9]`. Each element of the array is a pointer.

`ptr[0]` is a pointer to the string literal `"ram"`; `ptr[1]` is a pointer to the string literal `"try"`. All the 8 other elements are null pointers (`NULL`).

`*ptr[k]` is the first character in (the string) `ptr[k]` if it's not `NULL`

> `printf("%s \n",ptr);` prints neither string nor character (may be address)(why ?)

The `"%s"` specifier expects a value of type `char*`, you're passing the whole array of 10 pointers (type `char *[10]`) which is not compatible so you invoke **Undefined Behaviour**.

> `printf("%s \n",*ptr);` prints string (why ?)

`*ptr` is a synonym of `ptr[0]`. It's one of the array elements and has type `char*`. It's not `NULL`, so it works as expected.

> `printf("%c \n",*ptr[0]);` prints character i.e. r ( why ?)

`*ptr[0]` is the same as `ptr[0][0]` (or `(ptr[0])[0]`), ie ... the 1st character of the first pointer (the 1st string). It matches the specifier `"%c"` so it works as expected.

> `printf("%s \n",ptr[0]);` prints string (understandable)

See `*ptr` above; they're the same.

Answer (score 2):

Given the declaration

```
char *ptr[10] = {"ram", "try"};
```

the following are all true:

```
Expression        Type        "Decays" to      Value
----------        ----        -----------      -----
       ptr        char *[10]  char **          Address of first element (equivalent to &ptr[0]);
                                               not the correct type for the "%s" conversion 
                                               specifier in printf

      *ptr        char *      n/a              Value of first element;
                                               exactly equivalent to ptr[0]; correct type
                                               for "%s" conversion specifier

    ptr[0]        char *      n/a              Same as above

    ptr[i]        char *      n/a              Value of the i'th element

   *ptr[i]        char        n/a              Value of the first character
                                               of the i'th element
```

Graphically:

```
     char *                   char
     +---+                    +---+---+---+---+
ptr: |   | ptr[0] ----------> |'t'|'r'|'y'| 0 |
     +---+                    +---+---+---+---+
     |   | ptr[1] --------+
     +---+                |   +---+---+---+---+
     |   | ptr[2] ---|||  +-> |'r'|'a'|'m'| 0 |
     +---+                    +---+---+---+---+
     |   | ptr[3] ---|||
     +---+
      ...
```

where `|||` represents `NULL`.

Comment: I wonder if the types of the string literals in the diagram ought to be labelled as `char [4]` rather than `char`? It depends if you mean the type to be attached to the element or to the whole array. The way you have it does have the advantage of the arrows showing a dereference from `char *` to `char` though, which is good.

Comment: @Ian - The type is supposed to be for each element, not the whole block - I just edited the type on `ptr` from `char *[10]` to `char *`, as that what each element is.  I really suck at consistent notation.

Answer (score 1):

> `printf("%s \n",ptr);   // prints neither string nor character (may be address)(why ?)`

`ptr` is not a string.  It is an array of strings.

> `printf("%s \n",ptr[0]);   // prints string (understandable)`

Right.  `ptr` is an array of strings, so `ptr[0]` is one of those strings.

> `printf("%s \n",*ptr);  // prints string (why ?)`

Because `ptr` is an array of strings, and `*ptr` is identical to `ptr[0]`.

> `printf("%c \n",*ptr[0]);   // prints character i.e. r ( why ?)`

`ptr` is an array of strings, so `ptr[0]` is one of those strings, and `*ptr[0]` is one of the characters in one of those strings.

It might be interesting to note that

```
printf("%c\n", ptr[0][0]);
```

would give exactly the same result -- that is, print the first character of the first string, just like `*ptr[0]`.

What we're dancing around here, and what you may not have been taught properly yet, is what's sometimes called the *correspondence between arrays and pointers in C*.  Array subscripting in C is defined in terms of pointer arithmetic.  For any array `a` or pointer `p`, `a[i]` is by definition identical to `*(a + i)`, and `p[i]` is by definition identical to `*(p + i)`.

Answer (score 0):

Another interesting fact: whenever you use string literals in C Code, consider adding the const keyword. Because if you try to modify one of these strings, this will cause undefined behaviour (most likely a segmentation fault, which in turn means that your program will crash).

This will most likely crash:

```
char *foo = "bar";
foo[1] = 'x'; // Undefined behavior but compiles fine
```

This will prevent one from editing the content of the array:

```
const char *foo = "bar";
foo[1] = 'x'; // Won't compile
```